# invoke windows azure powershell webjob from windows azure website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have Windows Azure Powershell webjob which is myJob.ps1 file. I want to invoke this from my azure website. I have Button called "Invoke Webjob" when it trigger i have to invoke myJob.ps1 file. Is it possible to invoke this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't invoke a Webjob however, using the Azure WebJobs SDK, your job can listen to a message sent to a queue by your Website.  Not sure however if this will work with a PowerShell script but worth exploring.

Check this Azure documentation page for more info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/

Comment: yes exactly. what i did i run new process inside the webjob like in next ans. thanks. it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

All webjob executables will be sitting under your site's wwwroot\App_Data folder.

You can run those executables like you would execute any process from your site (for example, by using `Process.Start("path\to\exe")` if you're using C#)

Comment: no sorry you are little wrong all process run form temp in azure. so we need to find exat URI of file to process with particular application like command prompt.

Comment: @JenishZinzuvadiya, it's true that the webjob processes run from temp, but those binaries are originally placed under the wwwroot\App_Data folder and are copied to the temp folder from there. You can invoke them from the www\app_data folder directly

Comment: @JenishZinzuvadiya, FYI, this is exactly what the [DaaS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/daas/) site extension does

Comment: hey i try to start powershell.exe in my console webjob but it not working. I want to create new website via powershell script can you help me.